# disable horizontal scrolling by finger swipe

Tags: javascript, css, horizontal-scrolling

This may just be a mac issue, but I have a page with an element which is twice the size of the page and is moved into view dynamically. **in my css I have overflow-x:hidden** set so that this element won't create an ugly bottom scollbar, the problem is on my laptop (and probably on ipads and other devices) I can just swipe with two fingers to scroll and view this content. This breaks the whole layout and looks really bad, and **I am looking for a way to completely disable this horizontal scrolling action with javascript or css.**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
 window.onscroll = function () {
     window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
```

This will return the scroll bar back to it's original (0,0) location whenever the user tries to scroll. Let me know if this works with a laptop pad as I am on a desktop.

Comment: is it possible to use this to disable horizontal scrolling only? I want to allow vertical scrolling.

Comment: This doesn't work. it locks the screen in place and prevents all scrolling.  Also, even if you change it to: window.scrollTo(0,jQuery(window).scrollTop());
the scrolling vertically is severely hindered. try my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

First I used a function to check when the scrolling had stopped. then i used another function to move back to the center.

```
(function(){

var special = jQuery.event.special,
    uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
    uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

special.scrollstart = {
    setup: function() {

        var timer,
            handler =  function(evt) {

                var _self = this,
                    _args = arguments;

                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                } else {
                    evt.type = 'scrollstart';
                    jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                }

                timer = setTimeout( function(){
                    timer = null;
                }, special.scrollstop.latency);

            };

        jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid1, handler);

    },
    teardown: function(){
        jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid1) );
    }
};

special.scrollstop = {
    latency: 300,
    setup: function() {

        var timer,
                handler = function(evt) {

                var _self = this,
                    _args = arguments;

                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }

                timer = setTimeout( function(){

                    timer = null;
                    evt.type = 'scrollstop';
                    jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);

                }, special.scrollstop.latency);

            };

        jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid2, handler);

    },
    teardown: function() {
        jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid2) );
    }
};

})();

jQuery(window).bind('scrollstop', function(e){
  // block horizontal scrolling
  window.scrollTo(0,jQuery(window).scrollTop()); 
});
```